# How to know which version of Hive am I using?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am new to running Hive queries.
I have a requirement to concatenate all the rows from a group by query into a single comma separated field.
There was an answer on stackoverflow showing that there is a limitation to do this based on the version of Hadoop, I am using.
So, I have two questions.

1. How to know which version I am using?
2. How to concatenate all rows into a single comma separated field based on Group by query?

Comment: For the Hive version, you'll probably need to locate the jar file that runs Hive, usually in `/usr/lib/hive/lib` or some similar path. The jar will look like `hive-[version]-[distribution].jar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ad. 1). Run

```
$ $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive --version
Hive 0.14.0
Subversion file:///Users/ghagleitner/Projects/hive-svn/rel-prep/hive-14-rel-prep -r Unknown
Compiled by ghagleitner on Sat Nov 8 23:25:06 PST 2014
From source with checksum 49c2182a0856f7917f571802a7594b00
```

ad. 2). If you need unique values use collect_set, otherwise use collect_list, e.g.

```
select column_1, collect_list(columnt_2) from table group by column_1
```

Comment: collect_list is giving me the result as a space separated field. Can I introduce any separator like a comma or a '~' for each field using collect_list?